# Не передается значение в функцию

Tags: c#, jquery

В проекте VS пробую передать значение, которые получил из C# в функцию JS через `a href` почему-то выходит "*Заполнить*", вместо значения value="**1**". Новичок не судить строго :) Всем спасибо.

**C#**

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell tc = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell();
tc.Text = "<a title='Заполнить данные на " + arr.fio + "'class='btn btn-success btn-xs' onclick='_test(this);' value="1">Заполнить</a>";                    
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
```

**JS**

```
function _test(this_){
    alert(this_.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function _test(this_){
    alert(this_.getAttribute('value'));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, супер :)